# Reference to derived class does not get assigned in Xamarin

Tags: c#, polymorphism, xamarin

I have written a code which works in **VS Studio**, but doesn't work in **Xamarin**. It's a simple C# code and the polymorphism behavior.

The code is very simple. First I created an abstract base class and then a derived class:

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
abstract public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nummer { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public string PLZ { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
    public string Land { get; set;}
    public string Telefon { get; set;}
    public string Email { get; set;}
    public string Geburtstag { get; set;}
    protected Person()
    {

    }
    public virtual string GetID()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }
}
public class Kunde : Person
{
    public string ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nummer { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public string PLZ { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
    public string Land { get; set;}
    public string Telefon { get; set;}
    public string Email { get; set;}
    public string Geburtstag { get; set;}
    public virtual string GetID()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }
    private Kunde ()
    {

    }
    public static Kunde Create()
    {
        // ein ganz neuer Kunde wird initializiert
        var kunde = new Kunde ();
        return kunde;
    }
}
}
```

And now I tried out the following code:

```
        Person p;
        p = Kunde.Create ();
        p.Name = "sdlfkj";
```

But `p.Name` doesn't get any value. The same bunch of code works completely in **Visual Studio** in Windows Projects, but does not work in **Xamarin** (I am using version **4.2.3**).

It is the basic polymorphism behavior of C#. Why is it not working in **Xamarin**?

Comment: The `Kunde.Name` property hides the `Person.Name` property, and your code assign `Person.Name`, not `Kunde.Name`. Why do you redeclare `Person`'s properties in `Kunde`? They're already there, since they're inherited.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Yes, thanks, that was the reason. But why was it working in VS Studio correctly?

Comment: are you sure that you were not getting any warnings in the VS environment ?

Comment: I said warnings not error...there is a difference.. LOL

Comment: @DJKRAZE Sorry I mistyped. There is no warning and everything works fine.